# ul alignment issue html

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I have created a list in an html email as:

```
<table width="220" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr>
    <td width="20"></td>
    <td width="180">
      <p style="color:#333333; line-height: 20px; font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;">Title</p>
      <ul style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; list-style-image:url(images/bullet.jpg);">
        <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
        <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
        <li>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td width="20"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However the list is not aligned with the Title above. How do I align them ?

Comment: OK why was it given a -ve vote?

Comment: well the inline-styles aren't exactly best practice for one... but I understand this is an e-mail template where you might need them...

Comment: so your point is? HTML emails do not allow css in the header

Comment: I did not downvote this, and I mentioned that in my comment, and I fixed your poorly tabbed markup.

Comment: Also, see my updated `<html>` code. Fixed a lot of issues you had, removing a lot of unneccessary code.  I even used some example bullets, you just need to replace them with your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding:0` to your CSS style for your `UL` and optionally `list-style-position:inside;` if you want the bullets included within the text rather than outside (to the left).

```
<ul style="color:#767676; line-height: 20px; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; list-style-image:url(images/bullet.jpg);list-style-position:inside;padding:0;">
```

Answer (score 1):

See my updated **fiddle** [http://jsfiddle.net/KM9Wk/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/KM9Wk/).

I updated your `<html>` code.  Not sure why you had empty `<td>` tags on the sides.  I just used `padding` instead.  "Title" is also aligned properly.

Comment: That does not solve my problem, the bullet points have disappeared and it is still not aligned

Comment: The bullets aren't going to show-up because those images aren't on the **JSFiddle** server...